# VS Code, sync folder with remote host both ways

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using VS Code, and I'm trying to configure the [Natizyskunk SFTP extension](https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp) to sync a local and remote folder.
So far, I was able to configure it in such a way that, everytime I save a file on the local machine, it is uploaded on the remote one by using this sftp.json config file:

```
{
    "name": "remote host",
    "host": "remote_host_address",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "privateKeyPath": "/Users/my_user/.ssh/some_key",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "my_user",
    "remotePath": "remote_folder_path",
    "uploadOnSave": false,
    "watcher": {
        "files": "**/*",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "autoDelete": true
      },
    "useTempFile": false,
    "openSsh": false
}
```

However, I often work directly on the remote using SSH, so I would like to make the SFTP sync work the opposite way as well (if I modify a file on the remote, I would like the change to be synched on the local machine).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking into the same thing and so far the only thing we have found in the [configuration wiki](https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp/wiki/configuration#downloadonopen) is adding: `"downloadOnOpen": true,` to the sftp.json file which will download the remote file every time you open a local file to edit.